# android I want to show dialog in preferences screen

Tags: android, dialog, preferences

I want to show a password change prompt dialog from preferences screen. When a preference "Change Password" is clicked it should show a dialog prompting password and confirm password. I should be able to verify if the password are same.

Example is 
Settings->Location & Security->Set Password

I want to have similar functionality for my app.

Answer (score 0):

You should create first layout what the component arrangement you wanted as per (Settings->Location & Security->Set Password screen). And add this layout to

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
//Create Layout as per "set password" screen
builder.setView(layout); // Here set your layout
```

Hope this helpful.